# How to find duplicate content and make the last entry the master id?

Tags: mysql

I'm having some issues with **mysql** and I hope you'll be able to help me. :)

This code is for simplifying search results on a library website. One book can be published many time but the content of the book remains the same. This is why only one book needs to appear when we search for "Ze Book" or one of its ISBNs.

Here is the `table` I have:

```
id | isbn    | bookname | disabled | alias
1  | A-B-C-D | Ze Book  | 0        |
2  | E-F-G-H | Ze Book  | 0        |
3  | I-J-K-L | Ze Book  | 0        |
4  | M-N-O-P | Bookeee  | 0        |
5  | Q-R-S-T | Bookeee  | 0        |
```

And this is what I would like to do for `table`:

```
id | isbn    | bookname | disabled | alias
1  | A-B-C-D | Ze Book  | 1        |
2  | E-F-G-H | Ze Book  | 1        |
3  | I-J-K-L | Ze Book  | 0        |A-B-C-D, E-F-G-H
4  | M-N-O-P | Bookeee  | 1        |
5  | Q-R-S-T | Bookeee  | 0        |M-N-O-P
```

I do not know where to begin exactly and especially if it could be done directly with mysql.

For the moment, I've managed to identify the duplicate book names:

```
SELECT bookname, COUNT(*) AS number
FROM table
GROUP BY bookname
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
ORDER BY number DESC
```

Any ideas what to do next?

Thank's a lot in advance, as you may have noticed, I'm still learning how to code. :)

Comment: Why do you care which ones are disabled and what their aliases are? Why not just select the enabled ones?

Comment: @Strawberry there is an affiliate link for each book: the most recent published book is sure to be available on the marketplace. The aliases will be useful when people will scann their books to add them to their virtual library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be content with this?:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,isbn VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,bookname VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'A-B-C-D','Ze Book'),
(2,'E-F-G-H','Ze Book'),
(3,'I-J-K-L','Ze Book'),
(4,'M-N-O-P','Bookeee'),
(5,'Q-R-S-T','Bookeee'); 


    SELECT a.*
         , b.aliases  
      FROM my_table a 
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT x.bookname
                , MAX(x.id) max_id
                , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT y.isbn) aliases 
             FROM my_table x 
             JOIN my_table y 
               ON y.bookname = x.bookname 
              AND y.id < x.id 
            GROUP 
               BY x.bookname
         ) b 
        ON b.bookname = a.bookname 
       AND b.max_id = a.id;
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
| id | isbn    | bookname | aliases         |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
|  3 | I-J-K-L | Ze Book  | A-B-C-D,E-F-G-H |
|  5 | Q-R-S-T | Bookeee  | M-N-O-P         |
+----+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: With a little delay (over 3 years), thanks a lot! This has helped me in 2015 :)

Comment: Better late than never, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it whilst maintaining your table schema:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dupes AS (
   SELECT
      disabled_books.id,
      bookname,
      group_concat(isbn) as isbn_aliases
   FROM books
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         bookname,
         max(id) as keep_id
      FROM books
      GROUP BY bookname
      HAVING count(isbn) > 1) as disabled_books
      ON (books.bookname = disabled_books.bookname
         AND books.id != disabled_books.keep_id)
   GROUP BY bookname)
);


UPDATE books
INNER JOIN dupes USING(bookname)
SET books.disabled = IF(dupes.id = books.id, 0, 1),
books.alias = IF(dupes.id = books.id, dupes.isbn_alias, '');
```

Note: If the db is in active use, then you'd need to change that to a stored procedure to ensure transactional integrity.

It might be worth considering ditching the aliases column and moving it to a separate table to better manage this one-to-many relationship, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE isbn_aliases (
   isbn CHAR(13),
   isbn_alias CHAR(13),
   PRIMARY KEY (isbn)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8';
```